# Looping over a list to extract value in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm new to R programming, trying to write a loop to extract a number from a list containing dataframes. However, I can't seem to subset the list correctly. This is probably basic, but its driving me nuts by now!

```
df1 <- tibble("a"=c(1,2,3,4,5), "b"=c(22,23,24,25,26), c=c("alpha", "beta","alpha", "beta", "alpha"))
df2 <- tibble("a"=c(1,2,3,4,5), "b"=c(22,23,24,25,26), c=c("alpha", "beta","alpha", "beta", "alpha"))
df3 <- tibble("a"=c(1,2,3,4,5), "b"=c(22,23,24,25,26), c=c("alpha", "beta","alpha", "beta", "alpha"))
df4 <- tibble("a"=c(1,2,3,4,5), "b"=c(22,23,24,25,26), c=c("alpha", "beta","alpha", "beta", "alpha"))

list <- c(df1, df2, df3, df4)
res  <- vector("numeric",4)
df2[[2,2]]

for (i in list){
res[i] <- i[[2,2]]

}
```

I get this (and similar) error; "Error in i[[2, 2]] : incorrect number of subscripts"

Thankful for any help.

Comment: (1) naming a variable `list` is just not good, it's not always abundantly clear if you mean you variable named `list` or the primitive function named `list`. (2) in your `for` loop, `i` is a `tbl_df`, so "normal" frame indexing should apply, i.e., `[`. (3) `[[` is typically for single elements. (99) I don't know what you are trying to do here, but perhaps `i[2,2]` is what you need? (Note that it will return a `tbl_df`, 1 row and 1 column.)

Comment: Okay, I see what it is. You need to look at your `list` object: it is not a list of four frames/tibbles, it is a `list` (primitive R) with 12 elements named `"a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"` (yes, repeats), each a vector.

Comment: I think you meant `list <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4)` ... but I really encourage you to name it something other than `list`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, r2evans! Also new to this ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Up front, I'm going to use `mylist` instead of `list`.)

Your data is not a list of frames as you appear to be trying to use it as.

```r
mylist <- c(df1, df2, df3, df4)
str(mylist)
# List of 12
#  $ a: num [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
#  $ b: num [1:5] 22 23 24 25 26
#  $ c: chr [1:5] "alpha" "beta" "alpha" "beta" ...
#  $ a: num [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
#  $ b: num [1:5] 22 23 24 25 26
#  $ c: chr [1:5] "alpha" "beta" "alpha" "beta" ...
#  $ a: num [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
#  $ b: num [1:5] 22 23 24 25 26
#  $ c: chr [1:5] "alpha" "beta" "alpha" "beta" ...
#  $ a: num [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
#  $ b: num [1:5] 22 23 24 25 26
#  $ c: chr [1:5] "alpha" "beta" "alpha" "beta" ...
```

Instead, use `list`:

```r
mylist <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4)
str(mylist)
# List of 4
#  $ :Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame': 5 obs. of  3 variables:
#   ..$ a: num [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
#   ..$ b: num [1:5] 22 23 24 25 26
#   ..$ c: chr [1:5] "alpha" "beta" "alpha" "beta" ...
#  $ :Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame': 5 obs. of  3 variables:
#   ..$ a: num [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
#   ..$ b: num [1:5] 22 23 24 25 26
#   ..$ c: chr [1:5] "alpha" "beta" "alpha" "beta" ...
#  $ :Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame': 5 obs. of  3 variables:
#   ..$ a: num [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
#   ..$ b: num [1:5] 22 23 24 25 26
#   ..$ c: chr [1:5] "alpha" "beta" "alpha" "beta" ...
#  $ :Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame': 5 obs. of  3 variables:
#   ..$ a: num [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
#   ..$ b: num [1:5] 22 23 24 25 26
#   ..$ c: chr [1:5] "alpha" "beta" "alpha" "beta" ...
for (i in mylist) { print(i[[2,2]]); break; }
# [1] 23
```

(Notional `for` loop just to demonstrate that `i[[2,2]]` does work after all.)

---

And to your intended use, some working examples:

```r
res <- sapply(mylist, function(x) x[[2,2]])
res
# [1] 23 23 23 23

### identical results, might be more obscure (and perhaps less flexible)
res <- sapply(mylist, `[[`, c(2, 2))

### identical results, less R-idiomatic
res <- vector("numeric", 4)
for (i in seq_along(mylist)) { res[[i]] <- mylist[[i]][[2,2]]; }
res
```

Comment: Thank you for nice tips!
However, when I try to save the given value in a result vector I keep getting the error message "Error in res[i] <- (i[[2, 2]]) : invalid subscript type 'list'"
code: 

for (i in mylist) { 
  res[i] <- (i[[2,2]]) }

Comment: `res[df2]` is not a valid element of your vector. Try `res[2]` instead.

Comment: `for (i in seq_along(mylist)) { res[i] <- mylist[[i]][[2,2]]; }` perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you're trying to pick out the second row of the second column in each dataframe that is part of a list:

```
library(tidyverse)

res <- list(df1 = tibble("a"=c(1,2,3,4,5), "b"=c(22,23,24,25,26), 
                         c=c("alpha", "beta","alpha", "beta", "alpha")),
            df2 = tibble("a"=c(1,2,3,4,5), "b"=c(22,23,24,25,26), 
                         c=c("alpha", "beta","alpha", "beta", "alpha")),
            df3 = tibble("a"=c(1,2,3,4,5), "b"=c(22,23,24,25,26), 
                         c=c("alpha", "beta","alpha", "beta", "alpha")),
            df4 = tibble("a"=c(1,2,3,4,5), "b"=c(22,23,24,25,26), 
                         c=c("alpha", "beta","alpha", "beta", "alpha"))) %>%
  # if you want the answer in a dataframe
  purrr::map_df(~ .x %>% 
                  dplyr::select(2) %>% # Pick the second column
                  dplyr::slice(2)) %>% # Pick the second row's value

  unlist() # if you want it as a vector
```

```
> res
b1 b2 b3 b4 
23 23 23 23
```